# Automated Birthday Emails - Sent 1 week before and on the day of Birthday

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to set up am automated email campaign in SMC that takes the birthday field from a specific list and uses this to send 1x email 7days before the customers birthday and then 1x email on the day of customers birthday

I am new to SMC but i am so confused as how to set this seemly simple task up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is birthday email, you can use the standard feature of sfmc - [Playbooks](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/marketing_cloud/playbooks1/birthday_email_playbook/)

From the menu at the top, choose playbooks and then select Birthday Email to get started.
[image]

There are just 4 steps in this.  Follow the guided tour and you can complete it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the Playbooks - which I'll give you a limited wizard, the really technical method has many steps.

1) **Create your audience**. Assuming you are using Data Extensions then you could build a Filter off your source data extension. You will want 1 filter for '7 days before ' so that filter criteria will be based on `is anniversary of today - 7 days`. Similarly you want a filter for 'birthday today' which will have criteria of `anniversary is equal to today`

2) **Create your Filter Interaction** and associate to your saved filter and output Data Extension

3) **Create two User Initiated Emails** - associated to the email you wish to send and the filtered data extension

4) **create an automation** - to add each components together i.e. refresh your filter interaction and send email

You could also accomplish your use case with Journey Builder. A birthday email  is a basic use case so if you are new to Marketing Cloud then it's good for learning the various solutions possible to produce the same result. All the best learning it.